# Why I am getting empty 2d ArrayList such as [ [ ], [ ], [ ], ... ] instead of adding ArrayList in 2d ArrayList while solving power set/subset problem?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, subset

I am solving [Subsets Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) on leetcode using java with the help of recursion. But the problem is instead of adding ArrayList to 2d ArrayList I am getting { {}, {}, {}, ...} as my output instead of { {1,2,3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1}, {2,3}, {2}, {3}, {} }. Can someone explain me why this is happening?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {1, 2, 3};
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    helper(0, result, arr, nums);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static void helper(int index, List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> arr, int[] nums){
    if(index == nums.length){
        result.add(arr);
        return;
    }
    arr.add(nums[index]);
    helper(index+1, result, arr, nums);
    arr.remove(arr.size()-1);
    helper(index+1, result, arr, nums);
}
```

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jml62.png)

Also, when I write this code it work correctly. Why?

```java
public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList(); // pay attention 
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    helper(0, result, arr, nums);
    return result;
}

public void helper(int index, List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> arr, int[] nums){
    if(index == nums.length){
        result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(arr)); // pay attention 
        return;
    }
    arr.add(nums[index]);
    helper(index+1, result, arr, nums);
    arr.remove(arr.size()-1);
    helper(index+1, result, arr, nums);
}
```

[Screenshot of correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nzXr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `result.add(arr);`  , all `arr` that added to `result` are the same  one defined in your `main` function. As `arr` is [] at last, your result is `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`.

But when you use `result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(arr));`, you create an anonymous new `ArrayList` object, which has the same content as `arr` has at the time. But when `arr`'s content changed, it does nothing to this anonymous  object. So at last ,you got the result with different children.